# Compiling Android Qemu image

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu

I want to start playing around with Android. Downloaded the sources and followed the instructions from the [download page](http://source.android.com/download)

Made a plain generic build:

```
============================================
TARGET_PRODUCT=generic
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_SIMULATOR=
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=
============================================
```

But how can i create an e.g.qemu image from that. I looked around the /out dir,found the host tools and the emulator but dont know where to start to get this running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to build for the emulator?
if so follow these steps:

1. from your android root folder run the following command: "source build/envsetup.sh" that will setup the build environment.
2. to select the build for emulator option use the following command "lunch 1"
3. build, from your root folder: "make -j4" (the number 4 is twice the number of processors your system has, so if you have a quad core machine use -j8).
4. run the emulator: "emulator"

That should get you started.

if you need to quickly rebuild a subset and load the changes in the emulator use "adb remount && adb sync".

if you want to rebuild the system image use "make snod"

Hope this helps.